# How do I find files and total their sizes?

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to find a series of files (based on a wildcard expression) and total their disk usage.

Something like this:

```
$ find . -name 'flibble*' -ctime +90 -exec du -sh {} \;

2.1G    ./flibble_116.log
2.1G    ./flibble_83.log
2.1G    ./flibble_211040_157.log
2.1G    ./flibble3747_51.log
```

This work.  But it doesn't produce the result I'm looking for.  It lists the space used by each file, as `find` is iterating through them.

What I want is the total `du` for all of the files found.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Solution

By supplying the option `-c` (or `--total`) to `du(1)`, you can instruct it to produce a grand total. If your implementation of `du(1)` supports either of these options, you can achieve the desired effect using the following command:

```
$ find . -name 'flibble*' -ctime +90 -exec du -shc {} +
```

**EDIT:** Note that if the number of files exceeds the maximum number of parameters permitted by your system, `find` may still execute `command` multiple times. Some implementations of `du(1)` also support reading the filenames from a file, which does not suffer from the mentioned limitation:

```
$ find -name 'flibble*' -ctime +90 -print0 > filenames
$ du -shc --files0-from=filenames
```

## Explanation

The difference between the semantics of `-exec command {} \;` and `-exec command {} +` is the following:

- `command {} \;` executes `command` once for each result of `find`. The pathname of the result is passed instead of `{}`.

  ```
  $ touch 1 2 3
  $ find  1 2 3 -maxdepth 0 -exec echo {} \;
  1
  2
  3
  ```
- `command {} +` executes `command`, when all the results have been retrieved. The pathnames of the results are passed instead of `{}`.

  ```
  $ touch 1 2 3
  $ find  1 2 3 -maxdepth 0 -exec echo {} +
  1 2 3
  ```

The `-print0` option causes `find(1)` to print the found filenames to the standard output separated by the null character, and the `--files0-from` option caused `du(1)` to read the null-separated filenames. Unlike the new line character, the null character may not appear in a filename, so the output is unambiguous.

To learn more about the options of `du(1)` and `find(1)`, you should consult the respective manpages:

```
$ man du
$ man find
```

Comment: You might end up with multiple totals if the number of files is important (1K+) because of the number of command line arguments limitation.

Comment: I can confirm @ychaouche, I got the problem while trying to assess the size of more than 30k files.

Comment: If that's an issue, some implementations of `du(1)` also support reading the filenames from a file: `find  1 2 3 -maxdepth 0 -print0 > filenames; du -shc --files0-from=filenames`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
du -c `find . -name 'flibble*' -ctime +90` | tail -1
```

The original command is giving du one argument, then executing it, until it goes through all the arguments. This way, you simply are giving it all the arguments at once, then cutting off the separate sizes, and leaving only the total. You can remove the pipe and tail to show the size of each file if you'd like.

Comment: This won't produce correct results with pathnames containing spaces. The right way to do this is using the `-exec du -c {} +` option of `find`, which will pass the pathnames unaltered to `du`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
find . -name 'flibble*' -ctime +90 -exec du -ch {} + | grep total
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have `find` itself print out the size, and use another tool to calculate the total:

```
find . -name 'flibble*' -ctime +90 -printf "%s\n" |
perl -lnE '$sum += $_} END {say $sum'
```

If you also want to see the filenames:

```
find . -name 'flibble*' -ctime +90 -printf "%s\t%p\n" |
perl -apE '$sum += $F[0]} END {say $sum'
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner that should work to get a Gigabyte total on most systems:

```
echo "$(( ($(find . -name 'flibble*' -ctime +90 -type f -printf '%k+' )0)/1024/1024 )) GB"
```